# How to deal with simple problem with sqlite3 [sqlite3.OperationalError: incomplete input]

Tags: python

I have a problem with executed database / table creation. I am just start learning in this field so I have many knowledge gaps. I have code like this:

```
import sqlite3
import csv

connection = sqlite3.connect("sqlite.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()

table = (" CREATE TABLE NR_CELLS (\n"
         "            site_name TEXT\n"
         "            cell_name TEXT\n"
         "            physical_cell_id INTEGER\n"
         "            NCI INTEGER\n"
         "            downlink_narfcn INTEGER\n"
         "            downlink_bandwidth INTEGER\n"
         "            max_transmit_power INTEGER\n"
         "            ")
cursor.execute(table)

with open("dane_wejsciowe.txt", "rt") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter="\t")
    objects = []

    MeContextId_lst = []
    userLabel_lst = []
    nRPCI_lst = []
    nCI_lst = []
    arfcnDL_lst = []
    bSChannelBwDL_lst = []
    maxTransmissionPower_lst = []

    for row in csv_reader:
        if row:
            if row[0].startswith("FDN"):
                objects.append((row[0].split()[2:][0]))
        if row:
            if row[0].startswith("MeContextId"):
                MeContextId_lst.append(row[0].split()[2:][0])
        if row:
            if row[0].startswith("userLabel"):
                userLabel_lst.append(row[0].split()[2:][0])

        if row:
            if row[0].startswith("nRPCI"):
                nRPCI_lst.append(row[0].split()[2:][0][1:3])
        if row:
            if row[0].startswith("nCI"):
                nCI_lst.append(row[0].split()[2:][0][1:3])
        if row:
            if row[0].startswith("arfcnDL"):
                arfcnDL_lst.append(row[0].split()[2:][0][1:3])

        if row:
            if row[0].startswith("bSChannelBwDL"):
                bSChannelBwDL_lst.append(row[0].split()[2:][0][1:3])

        if row:
            if row[0].startswith("maxTransmissionPower"):
                maxTransmissionPower_lst.append(row[0].split()[2:][0][1:3])

rows = []
for o, u, n, nc, ar, bs, max in zip(objects, userLabel_lst, nRPCI_lst, nCI_lst, arfcnDL_lst, bSChannelBwDL_lst, maxTransmissionPower_lst):
    row = tuple((o, u, n, nc, ar, bs, max))
    rows.append(row)

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO sqlite Values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?", rows)

print("Command executed successfully...")

connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

I need just create simple database with table like above, but I have error like this:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: incomplete input

What am I doing wrong? where is the error exactly?

Comment: At least this `"INSERT INTO sqlite Values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?"` looks like it's missing `)`

Comment: You need a comma after each field definition in the `CREATE TABLE` statement.  Newlines don't mean anything to SQL.    So `site_name TEXT, cell_name TEXT,` etc.

Comment: @ James Z. and @Tim Roberti, still the sam eerror.

Comment: Unless your CSV file contains empty rows, you don't need ANY of those `if row:` statement.  If it does, just do `if not row: continue` once instead of repeating it 10 times.  Based on your splits, I'm guessing you don't really have a CSV file at all.  What is the imput?

Comment: If you're trying to enter many rows at once, you need `cursor.executemany`, not `cursor.execute`.

Comment: You don't have a closing paren in the `CREATE TABLE` statement either.  Have you run these queries in the command line sqlite to make sure they work?

Comment: There's very little about your script that is sensible.  Show us your input file, and we'll offer you meaningful advice.

Comment: @Tim Roberts, my input file is .txt format, not any particular, and it has empty rows

Comment: ".txt format" doesn't mean anything.  I mean LITERALLY, show us some of the input lines.'

Comment: @TimRoberts I've got update the quesions, literally I need to add many rows into table.

Comment: @TimRoberts Can you provide me some links from where I could improve my skills, so I could learn by myself? Please

Answer (score 0):

my code after correction:

```
import sqlite3
import csv

connection = sqlite3.connect("sqlite.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()

table = """ CREATE TABLE NR_CELLS (
            site_name TEXT,
            cell_name TEXT,
            physical_cell_id INTEGER,
            NCI INTEGER,
            downlink_narfcn INTEGER,
            downlink_bandwidth INTEGER,
            max_transmit_power INTEGER
            """
cursor.execute(table)

with open("dane_wejsciowe.txt", "rt") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter="\t")

    objects = []
    MeContextId_lst = []
    userLabel_lst = []
    nRPCI_lst = []
    nCI_lst = []
    arfcnDL_lst = []
    bSChannelBwDL_lst = []
    maxTransmissionPower_lst = []



for row in csv_reader:
    if row:
        continue

    if row[0].startswith("FDN"):
        objects.append((row[0].split()[2:][0]))

    if row[0].startswith("MeContextId"):
        MeContextId_lst.append(row[0].split()[2:][0])

    if row[0].startswith("userLabel"):
        userLabel_lst.append(row[0].split()[2:][0])

    if row[0].startswith("nRPCI"):
        nRPCI_lst.append(row[0].split()[2:][0][1:3])

    if row[0].startswith("nCI"):
        nCI_lst.append(row[0].split()[2:][0][1:3])

    if row[0].startswith("arfcnDL"):
        arfcnDL_lst.append(row[0].split()[2:][0][1:3])

        if row[0].startswith("bSChannelBwDL"):
            bSChannelBwDL_lst.append(row[0].split()[2:][0][1:3])

        if row[0].startswith("maxTransmissionPower"):
            maxTransmissionPower_lst.append(row[0].split()[2:][0][1:3])  

rows = []
for ob, me, us, nr, nc, ar, bs, max in zip(objects, MeContextId_lst, userLabel_lst, nRPCI_lst, nCI_lst,
                                           arfcnDL_lst, bSChannelBwDL_lst, maxTransmissionPower_lst):
    row = tuple(ob, me, us, nr, nc, ar, bs, max)
    rows.append(row)
    pint(rows)
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO sqlite Values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", rows)

print("Command executed successfully...")

connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

my input file (part of it):

```
FDN : "SubNetwork=ONRM_P4,SubNetwork=POZRAN,MeContext=34_WRO1190A_1_DWORSKA"
MeContextId : "34_WRO1190A_1_DWORSKA"
neType : RadioNode
platformType : <empty>


FDN : "SubNetwork=ONRM_P4,SubNetwork=POZRAN,MeContext=34_WRO1190A_1_DWORSKA,ManagedElement=34_WRO1190A_1_DWORSKA"
dnPrefix : "SubNetwork=ONRM_P4,SubNetwork=POZRAN,MeContext=34_WRO1190A_1_DWORSKA"
locationName : <empty>
logicalName : <empty>
managedElementId : "34_WRO1190A_1_DWORSKA"
managedElementType : "RadioNode"
managedElementTypeList : ["Bts", "ENodeB", "EquipmentSupport", "Fgw", "GNBCUCP", "GNBCUUP", "GNBDU", "Mce", "NodeB"]
neType : RadioNode
networkManagedElementId : "34_WRO1190A_1_DWORSKA"
platformType : <empty>
release : "21.Qx"
siteLocation : <empty>
swVersion : "21.Qx"
userDefinedState : <empty>
userLabel : <empty>
vendorName : "Gruchot"


FDN : "SubNetwork=ONRM_P4,SubNetwork=POZRAN,MeContext=34_WRO1190A_1_DWORSKA,ManagedElement=34_WRO1190A_1_DWORSKA,GNBDUFunction=1,UeCC=1"
ueCCId : "1"
```

and the error is :

```
cursor.execute(table)
sqlite3.OperationalError: incomplete input
```

Comment: PARENTHESES MUST MATCH.  This is a rule in essentially every programming language.  You are still missing a closed paren in your CREATE TABLE statement.